# Does Owin.AuthServices support Identity Providers

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver3, kentor-authservices

Please can anyone let me know whether Kentors, Owin.AuthServices extends ASP.NET Identities providers. If it supports is there a way that allow to support SAML 2.0 in addition to WS-Federation and OpenID Connect whilst still using the ASP.NET Identity framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are unrelated. Kentor implements an authentication protocol, and ASP.NET Identity is about managing user data in a database.

Comment: Thanks Brock. But microsoft's WS-Federation supports ASPNet Identity. But SAML is not supported ASPNet Identity. So I was using Kendo.AuthServices which supports SAML with ASPNet Identity. Is it making sense, If not, please can you clarify.

Comment: No it doesn't. I think you're confusing the term "ASP.NET Identity".

Comment: Thanks Brock for the clarification.